# How do I return a input with a onClick call in Javascript, in order to print it out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm attempting to upgrade a table and I've got most of it working, however one function is bothering me a bit. I need to get the function to return an input with an inline Onclick. The actual return works, but I can't seem to get it to recognize the inline JS it's printing back out. This is just a simple function to report a state change for a variable when a form element within the table is clicked. I'm using jQuery DataTables and Javascript.

```
                return "<a href='#' id='changeStatusLink' name='changeStatusLink' onClick='setValue("+full.UserStatus+")' ><img src='<?php echo '/css/images/status_enabled.png' ?>' width='22' height='22' />" + data + "</a>";
```

Comment: maybe you can do `document.write()`

Comment: The question needs more details. What does the actual non php code look like [view source]? How is it being added to the page?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question. It's not PHP, it's Javascript and tagged as such. The actual question was answered, however. I was just about to tag that as the Correct answer, since I forgot to quote it, but that answer vanished for some reason.

Comment: @epascarello, I think your deleted answer was acceptable after all

Comment: I am not misunderstanding the question. You had PHP markup in the JavaScript and JavaScript does not see the PHP code so trying to debug with some mystery string is impossible.  I deleted it since you said it was not a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becasue it will render as

```
...Link' onClick='setValue(YourString)' >...
```

Do you have a variable YourString?

You most likely need quotes around it so it renders as

```
...Link' onClick='setValue("YourString")' >...
```

so you need to escape the double quotes

```
onClick='setValue(\""+full.UserStatus+"\")'
```

and hopefully the value does not have any quotes.

Comment: No, it should not. It's just a bit in this case and GUID's in others.

Comment: I apoligize, I didn't make the connection between your username and the answer username - However, believe it or not, the PHP actually works within the JS after it's rendered, and you were right with the answer - I just needed to escape it.